# Glyph of Warding detecting race?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Can a glyph of warding be set to activate if a creature of a specific humanoid race touches it? For example, could a glyph of warding be set to activate if a changeling touches it, as a way to detect a disguised changeling?

Comment: Is there a reason you think this *can't* be done?

Comment: Related: "[What is the limit to a Glyph of Warding's trigger?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/148364)" and "[Can the Glyph of Warding spell detect whether a creature passed or failed a saving throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125608)" and "[Is there a spell or effect that reveals or identifies alignment?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72748)" and "[How can you detect a Doppelganger?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176887)" and "[Is there a way to force a doppelganger to revert to its true form without killing it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/116365)"

Answer (score 6):

The spell says:

> You decide what triggers the glyph when you cast the spell.

With the unspoken but ubiquitous “subject to DM approval.”

Triggering off a race is allowed [subject to DM approval]